# JSON parse issue with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

This is the XMLHttpRequest object. When I put it on `cosole.log` it gives the following response:

```
console.log(this.responseText);
"[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99/forks",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99/commits",
    "id": "c7c0df592e99c0c34b99",
    "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99.git",
    "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99.git",
    "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99",
    "files": {
      "config.json": {
        "filename": "config.json",
        "type": "application/json",
        "language": "JSON",
        "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/c7c0df592e99c0c34b99/raw/70489beaa4953f89fc8848195371da6eca76164c/config.json",
        "size": 17911
      }
    },
    "public": true,
    "created_at": "2015-04-26T20:34:11Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-04-26T20:34:11Z",
    "description": "Bootstrap Customizer Config",
    "comments": 0,
    "user": null,
    "comments_url": "h"[…]
```

But when I try to use `JSON.parse` on it it gives me an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.

gists = JSON.parse(this.reponseText)

im supposed to be using this api https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/ and its supposed to return valid json according to that documentation

Is the above data that was returned by the website not valid JSON? Or am I supposed to use a different function other than `JSON.parse`? Or what is going on? Please help.

full pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/BWttNtXP

Comment: It's not valid JSON is why... how is it being produced? Can we see that code?

Comment: You need to replace starting quotes to single for start, because your inner quotes are double.

Comment: @ChavdarSlavov — That's possibly an artefact of the viewer that JSON was copy/pasted from.

Comment: its copied from the console of the firefox browser

Comment: And does it have the `"` at the beginning of it? It shouldn't have

Comment: Other than the string quote the JSON is perfectly valid, can you give us a reference to the full json?

Comment: It's from github. Im trying to use their api for getting gists via ajax.

Answer (score 3):

**Update: Problem Solved**

The root problem is a typographical error in the code. Can you spot it?

```
gists = JSON.parse(this.reponseText);
```

Corrected:

```
gists = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

OP's code code works normally once this change is made.

Well, anyone that's coded for awhile knows how easy it is to waste a lot of time on something as simple as a missing bracket or semicolon. And when you finally find it ... D'oh!

**Original Post:**

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the json source as the below code is able to pull and process the data fine. Click "Run Code Snippet" to view.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="background-color:steelblue; color:white; padding:5px;">JSON DATA TEST</h1>
Raw Data:
<textarea id="output" style="width: 100%; height: 40em;padding:0.5em; border:1px black solid;"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // synchronous request for testing only.
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/gists/public', false);
 xhr.send();
 document.getElementById('output').value = xhr.responseText;
 
 try {
  var data = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );
  alert( 'SUCCESS:\n' + data[0].forks_url );
 }
 catch(e){ alert( 'ERROR:\n' + e.description ); }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
    console.log(this.responseText);
    var txt = this.responseText.trim("\"");
    gists = JSON.parse(txt);
```

this way your pastebin html works ok